# Unable to view image using <img> tag when image path is relative in MVC: C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, razor, razorengine

In the view, I created an `img` tag. I'm passing `image source` and `alternate text` from respective controller. **But view is unable to show any image.** Following is the view that I'm getting.

[image]

When I viewed the `page source` then I got following text there. It seems that view got the path from controller and mapped it rightly, but still something is missing.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Index</legend>

    <div class="display-field">
        <br /><br />
        <img src="D:\abc.jpg" alt="Test Image" />
        <br /><br />
        <img src="D:\\abc.jpg" alt="abc" />
        <br /><br />

    </div>
</fieldset>
```

---

Following is the code that I tried.

**Added a model (Image.cs) like below**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Student.Models
{
    public class Image
    {
        public string path { get; set; }
        public string altText { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller is like below**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Student.Models;

namespace Student.Controllers
{
    public class ImageController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Image img = new Image();
            img.path = @"D:\abc.jpg";
            img.altText = @"Test Image";

            return View(img);
        }

    }
}
```

**And view is**

```
@model Student.Models.Image

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Image Index</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Index</legend>

    <div class="display-field">
        <br /><br />
        <img src="@Model.path" alt="@Model.altText" />
        <br /><br />
        <img src="D:\\abc.jpg" alt="abc" />
        <br /><br />

    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**Note**: I'm using **Razor** view engine. I want to read it using relative path, not by virtual path.

Answer (score 1):

Jamie Rees's answer provides a way to read a file from disk, however from my understanding you want a file **relative** to the project. **Note: referencing directly from disk is not a good idea, as the location of deployment may not be the same on all environments.**

What you may want to do is use *Url.Content* instead.

```
Image img = new Image();
img.path = Url.Content("abc.jpg");
```

I am not sure the relative location of your file, so you may need to change that.

Comment: I know giving hard disk path is not a good idea. I'm doing this for understanding purpose. However in real time, we store the image path in our database and at run time we read the path from DB only. So, in real, when reading from DB, it won't create any problem when environment changes.

Comment: Url.Content is for virtual path, not for physical path!! It will not work.

Comment: @AmneshGoel I would advise that it's still not a good idea. An alternative to to that would be storing relative path instead (e.g. /Images/abc.jpg). Then, you can set up a [virtual directory](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732107(v=ws.10).aspx) for the folder /Images.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve an image up on disk you need to do this:

```
<img src="file:\\path />
```

So you need to change your view to:

```
@model Student.Models.Image

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Image Index</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Index</legend>

    <div class="display-field">
        <br /><br />
        <img src="file:\\@Model.path" alt="@Model.altText" />
        <br /><br />
        <img src="file:\\D:\\abc.jpg" alt="abc" />
        <br /><br />

    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't give the hard path like that. Instead, use `Url.Content()` and give it the path to your image. The path is a relative path from your project.